# Sort a dictionary alphabetically by value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is my dictionary:

```
const dict = {
  "key_1" : "z",
  "key_2" : "a",
  "key_3" : "b",
  "key_4" : "y"
};
```

I want to sort it alphabetically by value so it looks like this:

```
const sorted_dict = {
  "key_2" : "a",
  "key_3" : "b",
  "key_4" : "y",
  "key_1" : "z"
};
```

This is what I think should work:

```
var items = Object.keys(dict).map(function(key) {
        return [key, dict[key]];
    });

items.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
console.log(items)
```

But it's not sorting at all:

```
[
    [
        "key_1",
        "z"
    ],
    [
        "key_2",
        "a"
    ],
    [
        "key_3",
        "b"
    ],
    [
        "key_4",
        "y"
    ]
]
```

Why is the sorting not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Comment: `items.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));`

Comment: that's the answer thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this code will help you

```js
const dict = {
  key_1: "z",
  key_2: "a",
  key_3: "b",
  key_4: "y",
};

const sortable = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(dict).sort(([, a], [, b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
);

console.log(sortable);
```

Comment: It doesn't sort lexicographically, so it fails for words since you are only comparing the first character.

Comment: please check it now.!

Comment: Yes, now it is Okay!

Comment: Beautiful and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a sorted dictionary in JavaScript. There is no guarantee that insertion order nor alphabetical order will be preserved, even if you sometimes get the illusion that it is, you should never rely on it. If you need order you must use an array, a set or a Map

Answer (score 0):

The following code will sort the dictionary by the charcode, meaning the order of the alphabet:

```
const dict = {
  "key_1" : "z",
  "key_2" : "a",
  "key_3" : "b",
  "key_4" : "y"
};

const sorted = Object.entries(dict)
  .sort(([, v1], [, v2]) => v1.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - v2.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0))
  .reduce((obj, [k, v]) => ({
    ...obj,
    [k]: v
  }), {})

console.log(sorted)
//{key_2: 'a', key_3: 'b', key_4: 'y', key_1: 'z'}
```

However, this will only work when the value is one character. Do you which for a function that also sorts bigger values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.localCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) as here:

```js
const dict = {
  "key_1": "z",
  "key_2": "a",
  "key_3": "b",
  "key_4": "y"
};

var items = Object.keys(dict).map(function(key) {
  return [key, dict[key]];
});
items.sort((first, second) => first[1].localeCompare(second[1]));
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dict = {
  "key_1" : "z",
  "key_2" : "a",
  "key_3" : "b",
  "key_4" : "y"
};

let sorted = {};

Object.entries(dict) //enteries gives the arrray [key, value] for each entry
  .sort((a,b) => { 
    //console.log(a,b);
    //if value is equal, compare with key
    if(a[1] == b[1])  return a[0]<b[0] ? -1 : 1;
    //else compare value
    return a[1]<b[1] ? -1 : 1;
  })
  .forEach((ele) => {
    //console.log(ele);
    //reassign to a new object
    sorted[ele[0]] = ele[1] 
   });
  
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = { "key" : [
  "key_1=z",
  "key_2=a",
  "key_3=b",
  "key_4=y"
            ]};


function proto (thisone, order) {
proto[order] = thisone;

}
function proto2(thisone) {
proto2[thisone.split("=")[0]] = thisone.split("=")[1];

}
 function trierMax (value, order2) {
 
 if (!proto2[value.split("=")[0]]) {
 proto(value, order2);
} else {
    proto("null=zzzzz", order2);
}
for (var y = 0; y < sp.length; y++) {

if (sp[y].split("=")[1] < proto[order2].split("=")[1] && !proto2[sp[y].split("=")[0]]) {
proto(sp[y], order2);
}
}
}
var sp = items.key;

for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {

trierMax(sp[i], i);
proto2(proto[i]);
}

for (var p = 0; p < sp.length; p++) {
items.key[p] = proto[p];
}

console.log(items);
```

without "sort"